# Protect directory setting it from root .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can I configure the root .htaccess in my host to protect directories instead of put each individual configuration on each directory?

Like this:

`/.htaccess (configuring authentication to /folder)
/.htpasswd
/folder`

Instead of in each folder:

`/folder
/folder/.htaccess
/folder/.htpasswd`

Comment: `<Directory>` isn't even allowed in `.htaccess`. Clarify your requirements what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't.

.htaccess files are inherently *per directory* configuration. That means having an htaccess file inside the `/test/` directory, is the same as having the same configuration directives like this in the server/vhost config:

```
<Directory "/var/www/document-root/test"> 
  ... stuff from htaccess file
</Directory>
```

because of that, you can't use the `<Directory>` container in an htaccess file. If you want to do what I think you're trying to do, have all the config either in the server/vhost config inside individual `<Directory>` containers, or have an htaccess file inside every directory you want to protect.

The other way around this, is if you have a single realm and password file, and you **only want it to apply to specific URI's**. Then you can use setenvif and something like this:

```
# set SECURED var to 1 if URI is a protected one
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/test/" SECURED=1
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/test2/" SECURED=1

# enforce auth if SECURED=1
#AuthType Basic
AuthName "Acesso Restrito"
AuthUserFile /home/public_html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Deny from env=SECURED
Satisfy any
```

So the `SetEnvIfNoCase` directives match the request URI and if it matches one in the list, it requires password auth.

Also, you probably don't want your htpasswd file *inside your document root*.